# "ApplicationUnderTest.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false" not working in 2013

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have a CodedUI test for my WinForm app, and I want the application to remain open after the test is executed. It's working just fine in VS2012, but not in 2013. 2013 closes the app. Here's the code that I am using. Is there a settings I am missing somewhere?

```
var aut = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(@"C:\Users\...\app.exe");
this.UIMap.RecordedMethod1();
aut.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
```

Comment: Are you willing to *not* use `ApplicationUnderTest.Launch()`? I would recommend creating your own launch application method and put it in an `Initialize` method (Test, Class, or Assembly.) I would have the Initialize method check if the app is running already, launch it if it is not, and then your app will always remain open after the test.